# React Native Animated singleValue.stopTracking is not a function

Tags: react-native

I have the following code to animate in React Native

```
Animated.timing(
    this.state.absoluteChangeX,
    {toValue: 0},
).start(function() {
    this.lastX = 0;
    this.lastY = 0;
});
```

Pretty simple, but whenever it's triggered, I receive the error:
`singleValue.stopTracking is not a function`

Here's where the error originates:

/react-native/Libraries/Animates/src/AnimtaedImplementation.js

```
var timing = function(
  value: AnimatedValue | AnimatedValueXY,
  config: TimingAnimationConfig,
): CompositeAnimation {
  return maybeVectorAnim(value, config, timing) || {
    start: function(callback?: ?EndCallback): void {
      var singleValue: any = value;
      var singleConfig: any = config;
      singleValue.stopTracking(); // <--------------- HERE!!!
      if (config.toValue instanceof Animated) {
        singleValue.track(new AnimatedTracking(
          singleValue,
          config.toValue,
          TimingAnimation,
          singleConfig,
          callback
        ));
      } else {
        singleValue.animate(new TimingAnimation(singleConfig), callback);
      }
    },

    stop: function(): void {
      value.stopAnimation();
    },
  };
};
```

I'm not extremely versed in typeScript, but `var singleValue: any` means that "singleValue" could be any type. In my case, it's a number. Since numbers don't have methods, it would make sense that this would error.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The value you wish to animate must be an instance of `Animated.Value`, or one of its subtypes. When you initialize your state, it should look something like this:

```
getInitialState() {
  return { absoluteChangeX: new Animated.Value(0) };
}
```

The fact that the type declaration in the framework method is `any` is just a lack of constraint, not an explicit invitation to pass any value into it.

See the [Animated docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html) for more examples.

Comment: Your supposed stupidity helped me a lot, as I was stuck with the same problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue sometimes (React hooks instead) when I forget to set my variable to the `.current` of the ref:

```js
function MyComponent() {
    const animatedValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0.0)).current; // Notice the .current
}
```

This may not necessarily answer the original question, but developers who encounter this error while using React hooks may end up here so maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue because I used the animated value `(2)` instead of the object `(1)`:

```
const animatedValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0.0)).current; // (1)
const transform = animatedValue.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0.0, 1.0],
  outputRange: [0, 100]
}); // (2)

Animated.timing(animatedValue, { // USE animatedValue, NOT transform HERE!
  toValue: 1.0,
  duration: 3000,
});
```

Hope this can help anyone that was new to React Native Animation (like me :) )...